# Export default in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How am I able to name an exported function? `deafult` gives me an error

```
export default() => {
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  setHeight(window.innerHeight);
}, 100);
});

return (
<Layout title="Success!">
  <Container>
    <Confetti width={width} height={height} numberOfPieces={450} />
    <Title>congrats!</Title>
    <Message>Stripe has successfully processed your payment.</Message>
  </Container>
</Layout>
);
}
```

I would like to name my function default but it gives me an error, is this possible?

Comment: Default exports don't have names. You can define the function with a name, and then default export it, but the default export still won't have a name.

Comment: What's wrong with giving it a name? `export default Component() { ... }`

Comment: Yeah i would give it a name to export then this component but it gives me error on the `=>` @ToddSkelton

Comment: You need to remove `=>` it's not an arrow function. `export default function Component() { ... }`

Comment: That's how arrow functions work, you can declare a `function` though, i.e. `export default function App() {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to create an export.

You can do it all at once with a `function`.

```
export default function App() {
  return <div />
}
```

Or you can use an arrow function and do it in two parts.

```
const App = () => {
  return <div />
}
export default App;
```

Which one you use is mostly up to preference. JavaScript users typically prefer the first and TypeScript users the second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const MyFunction = () => {
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  setHeight(window.innerHeight);
}, 100);
});

return (
<Layout title="Success!">
  <Container>
    <Confetti width={width} height={height} numberOfPieces={450} />
    <Title>congrats!</Title>
    <Message>Stripe has successfully processed your payment.</Message>
  </Container>
</Layout>
);
}

export default MyFunction
```

Comment: You aren't allowed to do that with `const` functions. You have to export them after.

Comment: Yeah @ToddSkelton you are right, normally I use named exports, I think is better to manage a project